# How to make part of an object solid like a cut?

Tags: texturing, materials, modifiers

I am working on a plate for a cup and I don't know how to make the bottom of the plate look solid instead of clay-liked. I used the solidify modifier and subdivision modifier and here is the picture of my current work:
[image]

I want it to look like this, a solid and clear bottom (look for the second image of the product):

https://www.atelierjapan.co.uk/product/satsuma-small-plate-ware-autumnal-plate-sara/

Comment: try adding nore edge loops near the edges where you want to add a sharp or hard edge

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with supporting geometry. Make a loop cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> around the middle of the plate and slide it towards the center until it's close but not touching the center ring.

[image: Plate1]

If your center section is flat like in my example, you can add a loop cut to the center of that. Then select it and bevel it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to make it 2 loops that fit both the inner and outer ring.

[image: Plate2]

Do this as well for the inner and outer "sides" of the bottom rim.

[image: PlateRims]

You may also need to select the center bottom face and inset it slightly. The reason this works is that Subdivision Surface and flat shading takes the "average" between two faces and rounds the result accordingly. The smaller the faces are, and the closer they are together (such as those clamped in by edge loops) the less area there is to round, and are therefore the edges look "sharper". There are other ways of achieving this, such as selecting edges, and selecting "mark sharp", however I feel it's probably best to learn how the supporting geometry works first.

[image: PlateSharp]

Lastly, just finish it off by giving it a shiny material.

[image: Plate3]

Comment: Could you explain the usage of Ctrl+B in this situation? Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Ctrl+B is the shortcut to bevel a surface (usually a corner), however, I use it for a different purpose here. If you start by adding a loop cut somewhere and leave it at it's default position (right click) it will be placed exactly between the edge loops on either side. Since this is on a flat surface, beveling won't warp the geometry, it will just split the line in two (or however many iterations you choose using the mouse wheel). If you drag the bevel out using the mouse, the two lines will spread evenly, leaving them the same distance from the edge loops next to them.

Comment: Basically, it's just an easy way of adding 2 edge loops to a face that are equally spaced apart, and more importantly, of even distance to the next nearest edge. It just makes sure things stay uniform. Keep in mind, though this is not always the best method, as the bevel can mess with other geometry if your loop goes all the way around a complex mesh. For situations like that, it's best to add the loops one at a time, and "Edge Slide" them with G + G.